# how can i use mailComposer in iPad as well as iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have implemented mail Composer for iPhone and it's working Fine i want to use that mail composer in iPad also so what should i change or please Guide me how can i implement Mail composer in iPad?if possible then please give me a sample code also for that.Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI!I have implemented this code and you can implement it by just writing below code:

MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

```
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

mailController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[mailController setSubject:@"Hello iPhone"];
[mailController setMessageBody:@"Please Find The Attachment...." isHTML:NO];
mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ImgUrl objectAtIndex:offsetX]]];
```

UIImage *pic = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];

```
NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic ,1.0);
[mailController addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Picture.jpeg"];

[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:NO];
[mailController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine only if the Mail setup is configured in your Device, otherwise it crashes..!
So First setup the Mail Configuration and use this code to work.
**(Settings >> Mail, Contacts, Calander >> AddContact)**
it works for both iPhone and iPad as well
-- Ranganatha G V